# jquery tools overlay with prepend links

Tags: overlay, jquery-tools, prepend

I would like to run this overlay function after prepend.

```
$(".modal-link a[rel]").overlay({mask: '#000', effect: 'apple'});
```

I was able to get it to work by doing this:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".modal-link a", function() {
        $(this).overlay({ mask: '#000', effect: 'apple', load: true });
        return false;
    });
});
```

To me this doesn't seem like the proper way to go about assigning the overlay function to prepended links.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Here is my full source http://jsfiddle.net/gv93L/